# crosswalk cordova build for google play store

Tags: cordova, google-play, crosswalk-runtime

I have followed the directions in this post to migrate my existing cordova app to use crosswalk.  I did this for the arm library and this are working great through eclipse.

https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application

I'd like to test deploying the app to the google play store now.

I saw this article on building a crosswalk app in either embedded mode or shared mode.

https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/getting_started/Run_on_Android/Shared-mode

Is there a similar make script for building a cordova/crosswalk app for both architectures, or do I need to create two separate projects, one for arm and one for x86 and then use ANT or eclipse to create an apk?

I've followed this article and would prefer to build locally since I have everything already configured in eclipse.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/submitting-multiple-crosswalk-apk-to-google-play-store

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get crosswalk cordova working inside of android studio and now gradle lets me define product flavors (arm and x86) and easily kick off separate builds will packing the correct .so lib with each apk.

[Is it possible to use crosswalk-cordova inside of Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451623/is-it-possible-to-use-crosswalk-cordova-inside-of-android-studio/25512349#25512349)

Answer (score 2):

At current stage, there is no command line tool support to build cordova/crosswalk app for both architectures. You need to manually create two projects with arm and x86 xwalk_core_library respectively, assign different version number, build and upload them to google play store separately.

Just FYI, we are working with Cordova upstream to support build multiple architectures with Cordova CLI.

Comment: thanks for the info.  that's what I ended up doing, creating two projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a walkthrouth process for Google Play Submit crosswalk app from intel here: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/9a/72/Intel_Walkthrough_GP-Multiple_APK_Submissions.pdf

Comment: Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).