# How to migrate a Cordova app to Shared mode Crosswalk

Tags: android, html, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I have successfully migrated my existing project (in the case, an Ionic project) to use Crosswalk.
The performance of the app in the Android 4.0.3 WebKit was terrible and it was perfectly fixed with Crosswalk.

As expected the distribution APK size grew ~18MB.

Then I found the [*Shared mode*](https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/getting_started/run_on_android/Shared-vs.-embedded-mode) and I followed the directions to create a new project and it worked.
My apps's APK size was reduced and I got this running after dristributing both APKs.

**TL;dr**
Now, how do I migrate my Cordova app to Crosswalk - ***shared mode***?
Is it possible? Or does it work only with *original* Crosswalk applications?

**PS:**
This is not a duplicate of [crosswalk cordova build for google play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043782/crosswalk-cordova-build-for-google-play-store).

Answer (score 1):

currently crosswalk-cordova does not support shared mode.
We have added a task to make shared mode works with crosswalk-cordova, see:
https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-2751

Comment: it will be supported on xwalk 14